# How to debug libraries in Qt if currently loaded project is my application?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an Ubuntu environment + Qt.
I have libraries project and UI project

How do I load both of them such that I can accept input via UI project,
and then once the library is called on UI project, I can step through the library project.
In short I can debug both UI and library.
I added the static library file path on *.pro file but I think linking is incorrect.

I really have no idea on how to do this, I appreciate your help.

Comment: What does "accept input via UI", "library called on UI", "step through" mean? In general in most Linux systems you can debug any binary with `gdb my_executable`. Then you can set some breakpoints, run it, analyze stacktrace, etc. Is this what you want? Complete your question by showing your project structure and any relevant code.

Comment: create project with subprojects, include your lib project and your ui project as subprojects. (for example main project can consist of main widget and widget from ui subproject, then connect your ui subproject signals with lib subproject slots)

Comment: If both are currently open as separate projects inside QtCreator, and both are built in Debug mode (or Release with Debug symbols), you just need to be attached to the process that uses both projects and you will be able to debug both of them at the same time (I do it all the time)